# change a name of a folder in googlescript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Dears,
I have a form that make a response output folder "**MURAD**"
I want to change this **MURAD** to '`rowContents`'

where

`var rowContents=sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()`;

the script is

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow=ss.getLastRow();

  //the first column contains the timestamp

  var department=sheet.getRange(lastRow,2).getValue();

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------
  var subjectCode=sheet.getRange(lastRow,3).getValue();
  var courseCode=sheet.getRange(lastRow,4).getValue();
  var courseNo=sheet.getRange(lastRow,5).getValue();
  //var newResponse=subjectCode.toString()+"-"+courseCode.toString()+"-"+courseNo.toString();

  //here the new column with the file name is going on
  var newResponse=courseCode.toString()+courseNo.toString();
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  sheet.getRange(lastRow,7).setValue(newResponse);

  var secodarySheetId;

  switch(department) {
  case "Physics":
    secodarySheetId="1k2rOZfXjXHciPQh1pXn7-GP-p3rccMgT";//Paste here the Id of the destinationsheet in the Physics folder
    break;
  case "Chemistry":
    secodarySheetId="16-TOKctf8Y7nHyYFK8OgNIMCd9YQFvRT";//Paste here the Id of the destinationsheet in the Chemistry folder
    break;
  case "Math":
    secodarySheetId="1aPXI357UfQGdJnoxYfvtSq7GXhfizSSC";//Paste here the Id of the destinationsheet in the Maths folder
    break;
  }


//  var files=DriveApp.getFolderById(secodarySheetId).getFiles();
//while(files.hasNext())
//{
//  Logger.log(files.next())
//}
//DriveApp.createFolder(secodarySheetId)
  var rowContents=sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

var folders = DriveApp.getRootFolder().searchFolders('AlulaCR');
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  Logger.log(folder.getName());
}}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your code has to do with your question.

Comment: can you help me in a simple code to do the question?

Comment: How can I help?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function changeFolderName(oldName) {
  var oldName=oldName||"MURAD";
  var folders=DriveApp.getFoldersByName("MURAD");
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rowContents=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var n=0;
  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder=folders.next();
    n++;
  }
  if(n==1 && rowContents[?]) {//dont know which one you want
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    folder.setName(rowContents[?]);//Dont know which one you want
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Need Help. Found more than one folder with that name or invalid new name.");
  }
}
```